# How to extract a specific value from JSON and match its meaning with ListBox item

Tags: c#, json

I'm working on a small task. It's a small dictionary. I want to display the meaning of the phrasal verb when a listBox item is clicked

It's a small dictionary. I've created the API and here's how it all looks. I added to listBox the "complete" parameter because that's what will show the complete prhasal verb. Now my question is:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "complete":"wake up",
    "verb": "wake",
    "particle": "up",
    "meaning": "an instance of a person waking up or being woken up",
    "example": "the wake-up comes in the dark before dawn"
}
```

```cs
public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string complete { get; set; }
    public string verb { get; set; }
    public string particle { get; set; }
    public string meaning { get; set; }
    public string example { get; set; }
}

public void LoadJson()
{
    using (StreamReader r = File.OpenText("file.json"))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        List<RootObject> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(item.complete);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display the "meaning" parameter when I click on any phrasal verb on my listBox . However, I'm not sure what's the best way to get this approach. Should I manually add phrasal verbs for IF statement or should I parse JSON each time when the word is checked?
The idea is to SEARCH for a word through the textbox and display phrasal verbs on the listbox and show the meaning only when clicking on the listBox.

Comment: Use a `Dictionary` to store the key-value pairs you need, especially if there aren’t to items with the same key

Comment: You just deserialized to a `List<class>`. Use it as the `ListBox.DataSource`, setting as the `DisplayMember` the Prorperty you want to use to fill the visible list. When an item is selected, cast `SelectedItem` to `RootObject`, read its properties and use them as needed. For the `search` feature, start with `[ListBox].FindString` or `[ListBox].FindStringExact`, then maybe integrate the base functionality with LINQ's `Select`/`Where` etc. to create a more *complex* search utility.